# Cocoa: Launch console tool from Cocoa app

Tags: cocoa

I have two applications:

1) A multithreaded cocoa gui app.

2) A unix command line tool.

I need to be able to launch the command line tool from cocoa app *and* capture everything it sends to stdout. The usual approach with fork/exec does not work - cocoa application crashes with "fork in multithread" exception. Any ideas?

Thanks, Inso.

Comment: `fork` should work just fine as long as you `exec` immediately afterward. You should ask a question about that not working, and include your code and the exact exception message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html).